# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve not working in avqueue player

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have a `UIView` which contains an `AVQueuePlayer` to show a videos. `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` not working in this avqueue player

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:fff.mov"];
     first = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url1];
     NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:hgh.mov"];
     second = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url2];
     NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:jhk.mov"];
     third = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url3];
     NSURL *url4 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:dsdfd.mov"];
     fourth = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url4];
     player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArrayarrayWithObjects:first,second,third,fourth,nil]];
     lists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:first,second,third,fourth, nil];
     AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
     playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
     _displayview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
      [self.view addSubview:_displayview];
      [player play];

    for (int m;m<lists.count;m++)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:lists[m]];

    }
}
-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    End=YES;
    //   
    NSLog(@"view will Appear");
         [UIView transitionWithView:_displayview
                              duration:3.0f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^(void)
        {
            NSLog(@"IT REACHED THE END");
        } 
        completion:nil];
}
```

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate any advice.

Thanks guys.

Comment: in what way is it not working? what happens?

Comment: The view of the video is resizing automatically at end of the video and the animation is not working properly...